# Can I post a question about combining colors for an idea?

Tags: discussion

I have an image that I'm interested in using for a smartphone icon. Since the app is for the United States, I want to add the colors (or *something*) from the US flag to the image I want to use. That way, it's clear that the app is for the USA.

Can I ask these questions here?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a good fit to me. So, are you asking about software? Opinions on where to use the colors?